# wpf Access to 3rd party Themes and Skins via ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

I'm creating a WPF Revit Addin. For this I'd like to use some 3rd party controls for extra UI functionality and for their styles ([see ModernWpf](https://github.com/ghost1372/ModernWpf)])

Within a 'normal' WPF application it all works fine: I add the library (nuget) and added the themes resouces to the `app.xaml`'s `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`.

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ui:ThemeResources />
      <ui:XamlControlsResources />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Adding (for example) a DropDownButton control to a page and running the WPF app results in a working and styled DropDownButton.

[DropDownButton with styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uiP0.png)

In my Revit Addin this doesn't work somehow. Since there is no `app.xaml`, I tried to add the resources at different places (Window, Page, UserControl, my theme resource `MainTheme.xaml`, ... The control itself is shown and the dropdown action works, but there is no styling.

[DropDownButton without styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34wlF.png)

The `ModernWpf.dll` and `ModernWpf.Controls.dll` are copied to the Revit Addins folder, and these dll's hold the resources (as seen with DotPeek), so these should be available somehow.

[DotPeek on ModernWpf.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gp2s.png)

What am I missing / how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance, Michel

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, in Revit add in there is no app.xaml so no assembly wide resources either, this is because Revit add in is a class library, not a proper WPF application. You can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404019/assembly-wide-root-level-styles-in-wpf-class-library)  and take one of the approaches. In my add-ins, I fixed this issue like this:

Create xaml file with resource dictionary, for example "Resources.xaml" (to easily create WPF things inside class library, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224680/how-to-add-a-wpf-window-to-a-class-library-project))

Create your global resources in "Resources.xaml"

Create this class. Replace *name of your project* with name of your project.

```
public class SingletonResources : ResourceDictionary
    {
        private static ResourceDictionary? inst;

        public SingletonResources()
        {
            if (inst is null)
            {
                var uri = new Uri("/*name of your project*;component/Themes/Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                inst = (ResourceDictionary)System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(uri);
            }

            MergedDictionaries.Add(inst);
        }
    }
```

Then in every control where you want to be able to access "Resources.xaml", inside of control resources include SingletonResources. Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <revitPluginUi:SingletonResources>
        </revitPluginUi:SingletonResources>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now you can access all resources from "Resource.xaml" inside window.

IDE autocompletion for resource keys will not work.

**Important** note: if you need to create local resources for control, and you defined SingletonResources you need to define local resources inside SingletonResources tag. Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <revitPluginUi:SingletonResources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyLocalBrush"/>
        </revitPluginUi:SingletonResources>
</Window.Resources>
```